# Proving the inclusion map induces isomorphism on $K$-theory

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, k-theory

Let $M$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra, $A, B$ be closed, two-sided ideals of $M$ such that $A+B=M$.
Define $T=\{f\in C([0, 1], M):f(0) \in A, f(1) \in B\}$. Why is that the inclusion map of $C([0, 1], A\cap B)$ into $T$ induces isomorphism on $K$-theory?

I have tried the two common strategy for proving isomorphism to no avail. For one thing, I couldn't find a well-defined map from $T$ to the algebra $C([0, 1], A\cap B)$. (I was trying to claim that the said map is a homotopy equivalent)

The other strategy is via exact sequence, I couldn't find a contractible algebra to map $T$ surjectively onto. Any suggestion / hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(D)$ denote the cone on a C* algebra $D$. Recall that $C(D)$ is contractible.

Consider the natural quotient map $\pi : T\to C(M/B)$, then
$$
\ker(\pi) = \{f \in T : f(t) \in B \quad\forall t\}  = \{f \in C([0,1],B) : f(0) \in A\cap B\}
$$
Then one has
$$
0 \to C([0,1],A\cap B) \to \ker(\pi) \to C(B/A\cap B)\to 0
$$
And inclusion map $C([0,1],A\cap B) \to T$ is the composition of the two inclusion maps
$$
C([0,1],A\cap B) \to \ker(\pi) \to T
$$
each of which induces an isomorphism in K-theory.

Comment: Hi Prahlad, I have a followup question, why is $\pi$ a surjective map? It doesn't seem obvious to me that a path ending in 0 in M/B have a lifting to a path in M which starts at a prescribed element of A and ends at any element of B? It seems like some sort of path lifting lemma? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, surjective *-homomorphisms have the path-lifting property (because if $\pi : A\to B$ is surjective then the range of the map $1\otimes \pi : C[0,1]\otimes A\to C[0,1]\otimes B$ contains the algebraic tensor product and so is dense in $C[0,1]\otimes B$, but the range of a *-homomorphism is closed, so it must be all of $C[0,1]\otimes B$)

Comment: Hi Prahlad, Thank you for the reply! I got it now. I am wondering if the same would be true if the $\ast$-homomorphisms are replaced by bounded homomorphism between Banach algebras? (i.e. A, B are now Banach algebras instead of $C^\ast$-algebras) Thank you!